# Python TkInter: Tkinter.Tcl().eval() _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "exit"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tcl

I have a tcl package that need to do some clean-up on exit. For that i added in the package setup script the command:

```
trace add execution exit enter CustomCleanUp
```

Where CustomCleanUp is:

```
proc CustomCleanUp {args} {
     puts "Clean-up!"
}
```

When using the package from tclsh or a script run through tclsh (or wish) everything works as expected.

But when using it from python through Tkinter i get this error:
**_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "exit"**

To easily reproduce it run this code:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import Tcl
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import Tcl

tcl_interpreter = Tcl()
tcl_code1 = '''

proc CustomCleanUp {args} {
     puts "Clean-up!"
}

trace add execution exit enter CustomCleanUp
'''

tcl_interpreter.eval(tcl_code1)
```

For a workaround i can do this:

```
if {[info commands exit] != ""} {
    trace add execution exit enter CustomCleanUp
```

But this will mean that when the package is used from Tkinter, my custom clean up is not done and i can/will leak some resources.

**Is there anyway to avoid the error? Or make tkinter to call my clean up when the tcl_interpreter object is destroyed?**

Note: I only tested using tcl 2.7.5 and tkinter-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64 on Centos 7

Comment: is there a reason you're using a trace, rather than hooking in to when the window is destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Tkinter replaces the standard Tcl `exit` command with its own special version, which might be happening after you've connected your trace, resulting in the call not being tracked. It might be better to also track the deletion of a command or variable (which you otherwise need not use at all), which you might put in a namespace out of the way for additional convenience.

```
namespace eval ::deletion {
    variable detector {}
}
trace add variable ::deletion::detector unset ::CustomCleanUp
proc CustomCleanUp {args} {
     puts "Clean-up!"
}
```

It's entirely reasonable to *also* attach the trace callback to `exit`. However, I don't know offhand whether a variable unset trace or a command delete trace will be called at the right moment for you; cleanup happens at a non-trivial time during deletion of the interpreter context, so your ability to run code might be rather constrained. I do know that child namespaces are deleted before their parent, so that's why I'm suggesting that you use one for the deletion detector.